What are the reasons to skip a checksum in package build instructions?
When installing packages from the Arch Users Repository, I've gotten in the habit of checking the hash for each source file listed in the PKGBUILD.
Today is my first time seeing no hashes offered for checking:
sha256sums=('SKIP')

I've inspected the files in the original Github repo and don't suspect any security risks. But after seeing the hashes in so many other packages, I wonder: Is there a benefit or compelling reason not to offer a hash?

Ask the maintainer responsible for that line.
